# Stuck on background color change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried this project from a little while ago and even copy and pasted some parts from the working projects I had saved. The background color wont change and I am confused.

```js
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

const colorIndex = -1;

let myFunction = () => {
    colorIndex += 1;
    if (colorIndex > colors.length-1) colorIndex = 0;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
}
```

```css
body{
    text-align: center;
}
#btn {
    margin-top: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Colour Flipper</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="color.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Click to change colour</button>
</body>
<script src="color.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: `colorIndex` is defined as `const`, change it to `let`

Comment: BTW, if you run your code you would have seen the following error: "TypeError: invalid assignment to const 'colorIndex". Which would have given you some information on how to debug it.

Comment: Use your browser dev tools inspect facility to see errors which will be listed on its console.

Comment: just figured out how to use dev tools for this thansk

Answer (score 3):

**Uncaught TypeError:** Assignment to constant variable. Change constant variable

```
const colorIndex = -1;
```

to

```
let colorIndex = -1;
```

Comment: @goosey9 I made a demo in code editor online for you https://codepen.io/huykon225/pen/WNEExGN

Answer (score 0):

Use let instead of const. You cannot reassign const.

```js
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

let colorIndex = -1;

let myFunction = () => {
    colorIndex += 1;
    if (colorIndex > colors.length-1) colorIndex = 0;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Javascript. You initialise the variables with const. But you have to do it with let or var.

```
let colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

let colorIndex = -1;

let myFunction = () => { 
    colorIndex += 1;
    if (colorIndex > colors.length-1) colorIndex = 0;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
}
```